# cassandra - Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file to required size

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have corrupted sstable file on one node, when I'm running

```
sstablescrub --skip-corrupted demo test
```

command returns error

```
java.io.IOException: Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file   to required size
Exception in thread "main" FSReadError in /var/lib/cassandra/data/demo/test-1ac451f0265811e6b09b4342782e6533/mb-12248-big-Data.db
```

I don't know why the error occurs. Can I just delete the file, run cassandra and nodetool --full repair ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can turn the host off, delete the file and do a repair. It would work in some scenarios depending on data model and use case but I would not recommend it by default.

- If theres a tombstone past gc_grace in that sstable, all the other hosts may of purged it and without that sstable's tombstone shadowing real data it may get resurrected on a read and re-distributed on a read repair.
- If inserting with cl.quorum the data may only be on 2 hosts and with that sstable deleted, only on 1 host so on a quorum read you violate consistency (corrupted node + other node missing data respond before the node with the data).
- If inserting with cl.one then theres a chance that this host is only one with the data on disk. This is very unlikely given hints, read repairs, and commitlogs but its *possible* that data can be completely lost with a couple more issues occurring.

In cases of corruption I would strongly recommend just turning node off and replacing it completely. Even if its replacing with same hardware, re bootstrapping is safer than introducing windows where data loss is (unlikely but) possible.

If your ok with inconsistency in data, and a slight possibility of data loss then that approach is fine though.